# Get knob/thumb postion JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I need to get the exact middle or top point of a knob/thumb in JScrollPane, so the current focused component (the one with the yellow background) will follow the thumb. Is it possible?

[image]

ps. Sorry for missing the code example, but the implementation is quite large.

Comment: I think you'll need to make an example. It shouldn't be too hard. A ScrollPane and some sort of list/box layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a way to grab the thumb/knob of the scroll pane but I don't know it. Here is a geometric way to find what you're after.

We'll add an adjustment listener, then get the value of the slider. From the value we can calculate the fraction of the scene the slider is moved along. Then we get the height of the scroll bar and we can use the fraction to find the position of the knob.

```
double relativePositionOnScreen = height*model.getValue()/(model.getMaximum() - model.getMinimum());
```

The position of the knob on screen will have to be shifted relative to the viewport, so we can just add the value to that.

Here is an example, with a scrollpane and inside of the scrollpane is a panel that has a box on it following the knob.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class ScrollByMe{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 0, 0);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("scroll by me");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                ((Graphics2D)g).draw(rect);
            }
        };

        panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 800) );
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane( panel);
        JScrollBar bar = scroller.getVerticalScrollBar();

        bar.addAdjustmentListener( e ->{
            BoundedRangeModel model = bar.getModel();
            Dimension d = bar.getSize();
            double height = d.getHeight();
            double buttonHeight = model.getExtent() * height / (model.getMaximum() - model.getMinimum());
            //maximum *value* range.
            double relativePositionOnScreen = height*model.getValue()/(model.getMaximum() - model.getMinimum());
            rect.setRect( 40, model.getValue() + relativePositionOnScreen, 40, buttonHeight);
            panel.repaint();
        });

        frame.add(scroller);
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: You put a lot of effort into this for something hard to solve, and I agree, that the thumb component is something that is difficult to get a reference to (I tried) 1+